# Using a Delphi DLL in C++

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

How can I use a DLL written in Delphi in my C++ project (console application)?

I have already read about wrappers. Is there an easier way than that? Or how does this method (wrapper) work?

Comment: This should "just work". Have you tried it?

Comment: Do you need to know how to generate header and lib files?

Comment: As I remember there was a strange rule in Borland Delphi/C++ 6 DLL: if you had a function name: `FooFunction`, you had to look for `_FooFunction` by `GetProcAddress`. Additionally there was an application to change the DLL interface from/to Boralnd interface to/from standard DLL interface. [link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/coff2omf_xml.html)

Comment: I used  a DLL in c++ long time a go,as i remember there  was some borland tool that generate lib from DLL and I used it with my wrapper header tha I written;;

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial if you are compiling your C++ project with C++Builder. Just include in your code the C++ wrapper headers generated by the Delphi compiler and link your code with the Delphi library stubs.

However I am not sure if you can manage to do it if you do not have access to wrappers, Delphi source code or Delphi compiler. In such a case or if you are not using C++Builder you must apply typical usage of DLLs and follow standard call convention and COM rules if Delphi code is exporting OO features as COM objects.

Comment: @ Craig Stuntz: would you please explain this method? I can't find a good reference for that
I'll appreciate if you add an example. thanks a lot

Comment: @Alireza: Could you specify if you are interested in the details of using C++Builder?